# Refresh only internal connections in excel power query / Data model

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery

I have a rather large datamodel in excel. it consists of an imported data mart featuring one fact table and around 20 dimension tables.

I also have 3 tables directly in the excel sheet, where users can enter data, that then gets merged into the existing datamodel using power query.

I would like to be able to update the datamodel thereby updating the content of my pivot tables and my calculations, without refreshing the actual data coming from my external server.

Is this possible without having to disable external data connections i the sheet (I'd like to periodically update the data)

For clarification, i am building a KPI that will be measured monthly on data present on the 1st of every month, but will have to be analyzed, commented, and have outliers handled throughout the month.

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned VBA in your question, but going by the fact you've tagged your question as VBA, I'm guessing that's what you're using?

VBA code to refresh a single query is:

```
Sheets("sheetName").ListObjects("queryName").Refresh
```

If you're trying to do it manually, then it's just a question of selecting a cell within the table the query is pulling to, and then Query > Refresh.

Comment: I figured that VBA would probably be necessary, but no I generally dislike using VBA if I can avoid it, I'd rather put the logic up on a server rather than inside a workbook. If I do update a pivot that draws data from the datamodel using VBA, won't this cause a cascade load of the data source from the server also?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you want to update power queries from one part of the workbook to the other? You can definitely do that from within the workbook, as I've explained above. I don't know for sure, but I'm fairly confident that if you were to try and refresh the internal queries via an external server, then the server data would pull through as well, which you don't want. If you just update the query that is pulling data from one part of the workbook to the other, then the query to the server data won't be refreshed, as it's a different query.